# Algolia - Push Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, algolia

Following the [example](https://www.algolia.com/doc/onboarding/#/push-data) of how to push data to algolia, tried to connect only to Algolia with SearchClient, have installed the Algolia with .NET CLI (dotnet add package Algolia.Search) in VS Code.

The code is the follow:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Algolia.Search;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            SearchClient client = new SearchClient("SUMI5AMP4H", "Admin API Key");
            SearchIndex index = client.InitIndex("demo_ecommerce");

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

with command `dotnet run`

that returns:

> Program.cs(13,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'SearchClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)
>
> Program.cs(14,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'SearchIndex' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

[The project was created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code) with `dotnet new console`

So having the Algolia.Search package installed how does it not recognize SearchClient and SearchIndex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure it out, needed to take look at the package of the `Algolia.Search`, so to find the location search for Algolia.Search.dll as defined in the project.assets.json.

The path is the follow `C:\Users\{user}\.nuget\packages\algolia.search\6.3.0\lib\netstandard2.0` that where the package/dll is located now to see the code installed JetBrains dotPeek and opened the dll and search for SearchClient Class that was in Clients namespace.

So change `using Algolia.Search;` to `using Algolia.Search.Clients;` and already works and recognizes.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, there was an issue with the provided snippet. I've just updated it and my colleagues deployed it. You should now see the correct snippets appear on the https://www.algolia.com/doc/onboarding/ page.

Thank you very much for letting us know.